# css files are not appearing on my live github pages application

Tags: css, github, flask, host

I am hosting my flask app on github page. the index.html file is coming up on my webpage but the css and js associated with it is not loading up for some reason. what is the reason for this?

my index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Scrolling Nav - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="/static/static2/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="/static/static2/css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body id="page-top">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Stock Guru</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Prediction</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Graph</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header class="bg-primary text-white">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>Welcome to my stock price predictor!</h1>
      <p class="lead"> Where I use machine learning to train data sets in an attempt to predict stock prices</p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h2>About this program</h2>
          <p class="lead">The way this program works is by taking a large data set of previous stock prices and training off of them. Once trained, another data set is fed to the program; The testing data set. This testing data is fed through a linear regression model and spits out an output; The predicted price. </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Clickable nav links that smooth scroll to page sections</li>
            <li>Responsive behavior when clicking nav links perfect for a one page website</li>
            <li>Bootstrap's scrollspy feature which highlights which section of the page you're on in the navbar</li>
            <li>Minimal custom CSS so you are free to explore your own unique design options</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="services" class="bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h2>Here is the prediction for Tesla stock price</h2>
          <p class="lead">Stock prediction: {{variable}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h2>Graph</h2>
          <p class="lead"> {{image}}
            <img src="/static/images/plot.png" style = "width: 600px; height: 600px"> <!-- this part diplays by plot-->

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2019</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="/static/static2/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/static2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="/static/static2/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom JavaScript for this theme -->
  <script src="/static/static2/js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

my live site: https://amanpuranik.github.io/stock2/
my repo: https://github.com/amanpuranik/stock2

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going onto StackOverflow you should inspect the console to find issues. On your website it states it failed to load all of your css and javascript files 404.

Why did you put static/static2 in your links, its not in the repository. Consider looking at the directories.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're linking to your `css` and `js` files "relatively", however, you're prefixing them incorrectly.

1 - Absolute link example:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://amanpuranik.github.io/stock2/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

2 - Relative link example:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Quite simply, a relative link is relative to the current page, so the second example's relative url will map to **`https://amanpuranik.github.io/stock2/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`**

If you're serving contents from `https://amanpuranik.github.io/stock2` url, and your intention is to create a "relative" link to any existing file, you have to know its path... As you see on example 2, your `bootstrap.min.css` file lives here: `/vendor/bootstrap/css/`, down to your repository's root directory.

So in the end, there's no such directories as `"/static/static2/"` on your project, removing any reference to those from your links should solve the issue.